# How to display properly monomial in python with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, fractions, simplify

I've an expression that after simplify method looks like this: 
5*y**3/2 
I would like to see expression in this view: 
(5/2) * y ** 3 
but I have no idea how to do this. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be my approach: Try to extract the power (in this case y**3) and then you're left with the multiplicative factors. You'll have to make up some rules to determine where to place parenthesis. Then put the power at the and (with proper spacing).

Comment: `Poly` displays as you want (more or less), `Poly(5/2*y**3, y, domain='QQ')`.  But I don't know how extract the expression without reverting to the original form.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to modify the string printer, in particular the function that deals with multiplications. For example:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing import StrPrinter

class MyStrPrinter(StrPrinter):
    def _print_Mul(self, expr):
        if expr.has(Rational) and expr.has(Pow)::
            s = []
            for  a in expr.args:
                s.append(str(a) if not isinstance(a, Rational) else "(%s)" % a)
            return "*".join(s)
        return super()._print_Mul(expr)

def my_str_printer(expr, **kwargs):
    return MyStrPrinter().doprint(expr)

init_printing(use_latex=False, pretty_print=False, str_printer=my_str_printer)
```

Inside the `_print_Mul` function, I naively detected the multiplicative terms containing at least a rational number and at least one power. When that's the case, I return my modified string in which I wrap rational numbers into parentheses. Otherwise, it just uses the default printer.

I'm also using Jupyter Notebook, so with the last line I'm asking to not use Latex printer (the default option), not use pretty print (the secondary default option) and then I inform sympy to use the custom string printer.

Now let's try it:

```py
var("y")
expr = 5*y**3/2
expr
# out: (5/2)*y**3
```

Let's add another term:

```py
var("y")
expr = 5*y**3/2 + 2
expr
# out: 2 + (5/2)*y**3
```

Note that if we execute `print(expr)` it just doesn't use our custom printer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an object to do something more with, not only print, you could create a Symbol from the Rational coefficient:

```py
def inline(x):
    c,e = x.as_coeff_Mul()
    if c.is_Integer or not c.is_Rational:
        return x
    return Symbol('(%s)'%c)*e

>>> inline(5*y**3/2)
(5/2)*y**3
```

And if you want to make this transformation everywhere in your expression you could do

```py
>>> (expr + 1).replace(lambda x: inline(x) != x, lambda x:inline(x))
(5/2)*y**3 + 1
```